# form validates whole page in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I want to validate only part of the page in the same form.

However it validates whole pages textboxes like below. Here is the details;

[image]

Code behind is;

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
            .
            .
            .
            </ContentTemplate>
             <Triggers>
                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLogin" EventName="Click" />
             </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

// the section that i want to validate only below textbox using reset button however above one is validating too

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="tbMailForgot" minlength="1" required="" runat="server"  TextMode="Email" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"  ></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:Button ID="btnReset"  OnClientClick="return funcmail();" runat="server" Text="Reset"  OnClick="btnReset_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
             <Triggers>
                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnReset" EventName="Click" />
             </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

How can i do it partly ?

Comment: Which textbox you are validating? Please explain the problem specifically what error you are getting?

Comment: @ItiTyagi edited question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Validation groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx). You have to set each validator to a validation group and then set the same validation group to the submit button. For instance:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbMailForgot" minlength="1" required="" runat="server"  TextMode="Email" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
      controltovalidate="tbMailForgot"
      validationgroup="Forgot"
      errormessage="Email required"
      runat="Server">
    </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
<asp:Button ID="btnReset" OnClientClick="return funcmail();" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnReset_Click" ValidationGroup="Forgot" />
```

Comment: acceptable but not good for me. I don't want to use validation groups.

Comment: Why not? just curious

Comment: My whole page designed  for bootstrap and when i add validator group whole textboxes and page layout looks so bad.

Comment: well nevertheless i tried your solutions. Yes it gives me error like 'Email required" but still give me same error.

Comment: @johntrue It's still unclear what you want. The solution hardkoded gave should accomplish what you asked for. Also validationgroups should not break in any way your lay-out. Maybe you are not using display="Dynamic" inside ur validators

Comment: @johntrue The problem with ASP.NET and native validators is that those validators are based on the FORM element. In your case, you would need 2 forms, and you won't be able to do that with ASP.NET Webforms.